# How to add repetitve responses to a webpage using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to add a repetitive text response to a chat box in a gaming website in order to create an algorithm which guesses words based on a drawing and hint.

The website is the popular pictionary website : https://skribbl.io/

I've been working on the algorithm to guess the words based on others reply, I'm not familiar with Selenium and trying to just print some simple text in the chat/guess textbox.

The website opens up, but it's not printing anything onto the box. How can I resolve this ? Thank you

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return  driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")!=None

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files\gecko\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://skribbl.io/?p0YRvXqupiza")

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.util(page_is_loaded)

for x in range (0,20):

    textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("text")
    textbox.send_keys("1")
```

This is how the homepage of Skribbl.io looks like -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j0Jg.jpg

[image]

The textbox is seen at the bottom right-hand side where I want the input from my code can be found here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLazo.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try the following*

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

firefox_browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\gecko\geckodriver.exe')
firefox_browser.get("https://skribbl.io/")
time.sleep(2)
name_input = firefox_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#inputName")
play_button = firefox_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn:nth-child(3)")
name_input.send_keys("Drums3")
play_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

for x in range(0, 20):
    time.sleep(3)
    chat_input = firefox_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#inputChat")
    chat_input.send_keys("hello")
    chat_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Adding my second Python file into the input should be fairly direct. Thank you.